# JQuery Variable Syntax - Using variables in expressions

Tags: jquery

I was trying to get the immediate children divs of a div with id to-append.

I found this works:

```
console.log($("#to-append > div").length);
```

But since I am using that div quite a lot, it is stored in a variable:

```
var $toappend = $('#to-append');
```

How would I go about getting the divs length using the variable?

```
    console.log($($toappend+" > div").length);
```

Throws an error

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the [.children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) function:

```
console.log(toappend.children('div').length);
```

Comment: I would have never guessed :)

Comment: I really think variables should be allowed to be used in direct replacement of their value